# trigger in MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database with university data. I want to create a trigger that ivolves the 2 tables University and Student.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `university` (
`name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`uni_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`students` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uni_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
`firstName` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`lastName` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`current_address` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`current_phone` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
`year_of_study` int(11) NOT NULL,
`department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`uniId` int(11) NOT NULL,
`study_cycle` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`,`id_number`),
UNIQUE KEY `student_id` (`student_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_number` (`id_number`),
KEY `lastName` (`lastName`),
KEY `uni_id` (`uniId`),
KEY `uniId` (`uniId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I want the trigger to increase `students` of table `university` after there is a new entry in table `student`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER s AFTER
INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE university SET students=students+1
WHERE uni_id=NEW.uni_id;
END;
```

It gives me an error when i try to execute it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change `NEW.uni_id` to `NEW.uniId`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER s AFTER
INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE university
  SET students=students+1
  WHERE uni_id=NEW.uniId
;
```

or you should rename that field in `student` table.

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/521cf/1).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER s BEFORE INSERT ON student
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   UPDATE university 
   SET students = students + 1
   WHERE uni_id = NEW.uniid;
END//
delimiter ;
```

(And try changing the trigger to `BEFORE`)

Comment: the after should not matter, and giving the constraints in the table he should probably use an after...

Comment: ok, no syntax erors now but it says #1054 - Unknown column 'uni_id' in 'NEW'.